# Unable to properly pip install tsne on ubuntu?

Tags: python, c++, ubuntu

I have been trying to install tsne (https://github.com/danielfrg/tsne) on my ubuntu box. Error that it keeps giving me is :

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
command g++ failed with exit status 1
```

here is the point where my installation stops:
[image]

I have two questions:
1. is it because i dont have proper g++ compiler?
2. How can i get libcblas on my ubuntu box?

I think both of the above questions will be able to solve my problem. I have all other dependencies mentioned on the page.

Answer (score 4):

Your `g++` is fine, you are probably missing the package `libatlas-base-dev`, install it with `sudo apt-get install`.

Comment: I actually did that and got into various problems related to linkages and could not even import scipy properly after that which I resolved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788593/libatlas-so-3gf-cannot-open-shared-object-file